# marklogic data hub framework error while updating to version 2.0.2

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

I'm trying to setup the ODH framework on CentOS Linux virtual machine.

All the pre-reqs met (Java and ML version) and the hub updated me to version 2.0.2 but it showed me this message "In order to continue we need to update a few things." and when I hit the "UPDATE IT" button, I get the following error. I also tried "./gradlew hubUpdate" but no luck. Can anyone help me please? Thanks

```
Sorry. We failed to update you to version 2.0.2.

Exception in thread "ThreadPoolTaskExecutor-1" com.marklogic.client.MarkLogicIOException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8010
at com.marklogic.client.impl.OkHttpServices.sendRequestOnce(OkHttpServices.java:676)
at com.marklogic.client.impl.OkHttpServices.sendRequestOnce(OkHttpServices.java:669)
at com.marklogic.client.impl.OkHttpServices.doPost(OkHttpServices.java:3992)
at com.marklogic.client.impl.OkHttpServices.postResource(OkHttpServices.java:3293)
at com.marklogic.client.impl.OkHttpServices.postBulkDocuments(OkHttpServices.java:3401)
at com.marklogic.client.impl.DocumentManagerImpl.write(DocumentManagerImpl.java:613)
at com.marklogic.client.impl.GenericDocumentImpl.write(GenericDocumentImpl.java:23)
at com.marklogic.client.impl.DocumentManagerImpl.write(DocumentManagerImpl.java:605)
at com.marklogic.client.impl.GenericDocumentImpl.write(GenericDocumentImpl.java:23)
at com.marklogic.client.impl.DocumentManagerImpl.write(DocumentManagerImpl.java:589)
at com.marklogic.client.impl.GenericDocumentImpl.write(GenericDocumentImpl.java:23)
at com.marklogic.client.ext.batch.RestBatchWriter$1.run(RestBatchWriter.java:78)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8010
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:225)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:149)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:195)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:121)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:100)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at com.burgstaller.okhttp.AuthenticationCacheInterceptor.intercept(AuthenticationCacheInterceptor.java:45)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:185)
at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:69)
at com.marklogic.client.impl.OkHttpServices.sendRequestOnce(OkHttpServices.java:674)
... 14 more

20:38:21.212 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: com.marklogic.client.MarkLogicIOException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8010] with root cause
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:124)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:223)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:149)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:195)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:121)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:100)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at com.burgstaller.okhttp.AuthenticationCacheInterceptor.intercept(AuthenticationCacheInterceptor.java:45)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:185)
at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:69)
at com.marklogic.client.impl.OkHttpServices.sendRequestOnce(OkHttpServices.java:674)
at com.marklogic.client.impl.OkHttpServices.sendRequestOnce(OkHttpServices.java:669)
at com.marklogic.client.impl.OkHttpServices.makeFirstRequest(OkHttpServices.java:498)
at com.marklogic.client.impl.OkHttpServices.putPostValueImpl(OkHttpServices.java:2750)
at com.marklogic.client.impl.OkHttpServices.putValue(OkHttpServices.java:2685)
at com.marklogic.client.impl.QueryOptionsManagerImpl.writeOptions(QueryOptionsManagerImpl.java:158)
at com.marklogic.client.ext.modulesloader.impl.DefaultModulesLoader.lambda$installQueryOptions$2(DefaultModulesLoader.java:391)
at com.marklogic.client.ext.modulesloader.impl.DefaultModulesLoader.lambda$executeTask$4(DefaultModulesLoader.java:410)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Which version of the hub did you upgrade from?

Comment: It's failing to connect to localhost:8010. Can you point a browser to localhost:8001 and confirm that there is an app server on port 8010?

Comment: Thanks Dave. To answer your questions. 1. It's a fresh setup. I tried to install via the quick start app by following the instructions given here. https://marklogic-community.github.io/marklogic-data-hub/tutorial/install/. This error shows up in step 6. If I go back to the app after facing this error then I get UPDATE IT button and I believe it is trying to upgrade the project and fails with the same error.

Comment: I figured out the problem and posted the answer as well. Thanks Dave. Appreciate your response and it helped me find the root cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

port was the issue. Since I ran the Marklogic database using docker, I had to open the ports 8010-8013 as given in FAQ while running the docker container using the below statement

docker run -d --name=data-hub -p 8000-8013:8000-8013 marklogic:9.0-3.1-installed

Comment: Please mark your answer as accepted so that it's clear that this question has an answer. Thanks!

Comment: I am setting up DHF in my local system (no docker) still getting the same error. Any suggestions?